# Properly naming the continuity of a function?

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I have a doubt. I've been taught that the definition of continuity is that the value of the limit of a function at a point is the same that the value of the function at that point. If there's only right-limit, then the funcion is right-continous and the the same argument for the left-continous. Then, according to this definition, the function $f(x)= \sqrt{x} $ is right-continous and not continous? 
Because you can not approach the function from the left at $x= 0$, as the function is not defined, and therefore there's not left limit at x=0, so it is not continous. But there is right limit for any point of the function in its domain $[0,\infty)$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl8ML.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say, for example, that the function $f$ is continuous at the interval $[a,b]$, it means that $f$ is continuous (right and left) at each point of the open interval $(a,b)$, right-continuous at the point $a$ and left-continuous at the point $b$.

Comment: I have a doubt. In books like Calculus (Larson) in the 
definitions,theorems like Rolle's theorem, when they talk about continuity, they use closed intervals [a,b]. But when they talk about  differentiability they use open brackets (a,b). One can apply the same reasoning you gave above and use for diferentiability the same closed interval as for continuity [a,b]. Taking into account that the functions is differentiable in all the interval (a,b) and right-differenciable in [a,..] and left-differenciable in [...,b]

https://postimg.org/image/goafgwf71/

Comment: Why closed intervals are used for continuity and open intervals for differenciablity?

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with confusion wrt. terminology. A function $f$ over the reals is continuous *at a given point* $x_0$ if $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$, or, equivalently, if $\lim_{x \rightarrow^+ x_0} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow^- x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$.

We then say that $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $I = [a,b]$ if $f$ is continuous at every $x \in I$ and right-, respectively left-continuous at its end points.

The function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous on the interval $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: Why not on the closed interval? If you write up the definition of the left limit at $0$ how does it fail to be 0?

Comment: You are right, of course, Tobias. I have updates my answer.